# define function for constants in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, constants

I'm trying to define a function to hold the constant but is not working

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .constant('config1', config1)
    .constant('config2', 
        (function(){
            return {
                VERSION: 2
            }
        }())
    );

function config1() {
    return {
        VERSION: '1'
    }
};

})();
```

> console.log(config1.VERSION); // undefined
>
> console.log(config2.VERSION); // 2

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve by trying to do this? It sounds like you need to create a `provider` which can be modified in config phase

Comment: for one, you haven't defined the variable `config1`, which you are passing to `.CONSTANT()`  Did you mean to pass `config2`, or name the `config2` function `config1`?

Comment: `config1`, looks like you've referenced the func without `()` compared to `config2` where you use `()` in which case it will execute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u missed the config1**()**.VERSION;

Comment: that works. is this  the right way to create and use constants? thanks